# Content CSS not working in safari browser

Tags: css, html

i have used tick / checkmark symbol (✓) for bullets in unordered list, but this list is not supporting in safari browser Please suggest me...

Html:

```
<div class="leftcontentdata">
  <ul>
    <li>sffsdfdf</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.leftcontentdata ul li::before {
  content: '✓';
}

.rightcontentdata ul li::before {
  content: '✓';
}
```

Comment: What's not working precisely?

Comment: It may need the actual character code; https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/check-mark/

Comment: what version of safari? (please don't say 5.1.7...)

Comment: @Kaiido hi, yes safari 5.1.7

Comment: @Kaiido any other solution please

Comment: This is partially supported according to https://caniuse.com/#search=content. You might want to try another way like fontawesome font

Comment: Buy a real macOs system, Install macOs from a  VirtualMachine, or build an hackintosh. But stop using this Safari for windows. It is not supported by anyone anymore, the last update was made in 2012, with regards to web standards, it's like you are using IE8. So yes, a lot of HTML5 features and whatever APIs came the last 6 years won't work there. But it's not a problem, because **nobody** should use this software anyway, be it for security reasons (there were known security issues that have and will never be fixed). But for what it's worth, your code work just fine on current Safari 11.1.2

Answer (score -1):

I've tested your code in EDGE, CHROME and Firefox, and it's working fine so it's defenitely a Safari issue. Since I don't own a mac, I cannot test in safari, but I can provide some solutions that should potentialy work.

## solution 1

You can try to use the CSS escaped code instead. Like this:

```css
.leftcontentdata ul li::before {
  content: '\2713';
}
```

```html
<div class="leftcontentdata">
  <ul>
    <li>sffsdfdf</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

## solution 2

Alternatively, you can use a third party library ([fontawesome](http://www.fontawesome.com/)) which *should* work in safari as well.

```css
.leftcontentdata ul li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f00c';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- automatic -->
<div class="leftcontentdata">
  <ul>
    <li>sffsdfdf</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```