# CSS display:content not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, display

I've found that `display:content` doesn't work in Safari.
What is the alternative of it for Safari?
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997298/content-css-not-working-in-safari-browser).
But the answer was down voted.

Comment: I also have got the same problem.

Comment: Does the solution you found work for you? If so, we can mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: The linked question has nothing to do with `display: contents` ([spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#box-generation)) - if that is what you are referring to. The linked question is about pseudo elements.

Comment: If you are having problems implementing code, create a [MRE] within your question.

Comment: It can be useful if you add a piece of code to show you use case.

Comment: I imagine that you're trying to use `:content` incorrectly, or are trying to use a pseudo on an element that doesn't support them. Show us some example code.

Comment: Not because of my code. I found it from the document, but couldn't find alternative. So I posted a question. But why downvote???

Comment: I don't know who's down-voting you but its valid to do so since this question has nothing for us to work with.

Comment: Yes, your words can be right, but still nobody can tell me the correct answer?

Comment: I can probably tell you the correct answer once you have posted a valid question. `display:content` isn't a thing. Perhaps you mean [`display:contents`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)? but the link you provided is pertaining to the `content:` attribute that can be used on :pseudo elements such as `:before` and `:after`.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you're trying to use `:content` incorrectly, or are trying to use a pseudo on an element that doesn't support them.

#### Regarding `display:contents` declaration:

This is not well supported. 
Note that as documented in https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents:

> iOS Safari 10 and 11, and Safari 11 renders **display:contents** as **display:inline**.

Also note that according to https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#box-generation:

> Note: As only the box tree is affected, any semantics based on the document tree, such as selector-matching, event handling, and property inheritance, are not affected. As of writing, however, **this is not implemented correctly in major browsers**, so using this feature on the Web must be done with care as it can prevent accessibility tools from accessing the element’s semantics.

---

#### Regarding the `content:` property:

This is well supported but can only be applied  to `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. Some elements (such as inputs) will not support pseudo elements. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content for more info.

---

#### Demo:

Here's a very basic working example (tested in Chrome and Safari 13) of both the `content:` property and the `contents` display value.

```css
#somediv:before {
  content: "(prepended) ";
  color: red;
}

#somediv:after {
  content: " (appended)";
  color: blue;
}

#someotherdiv {/* pointless styles */
  display:contents;
  border:2px solid red;
  background:yellow;
}

#someotherdiv p {
  color:purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="somediv">
  Example of content on pseudos.
</div>


<div id="someotherdiv">
  <p>Example of display:contents. Note that parent container isn't rendered?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he meant how to display content inside pseudo element ;)