# Why the CSS content:''; isn't shown on safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

the following code contains a simple website that is supposed to display some text that changes with a short time interval. For some reason, this code works perfectly in chrome, edge, and firefox but not in safari. What can I do in order to fix this issue?

I couldn't find any tutorial for achieving this online, thanks in advance for your answers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
    .wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 20%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .wrapper h2 {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
    span:before {
        content: '';
        animation: animate infinite 9s;
    }
    @keyframes animate {
        0% {
            content: 'a better future';
            font-family: 'Spectral', serif;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        50% {
            content: 'a better life';
            font-family: 'Spectral', serif;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        100% {
            content: 'prosperity';
            font-family: 'Spectral', serif;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
            body{
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .wrapper {
                top: 50vh;
                left: 50vw;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Investments for <span></span></h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: content is not (officially) animatable. See [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties However, some browsers do support it as you have discovered

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413988/css-displaycontent-not-working-in-safari

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend it to you checking out **caniuse**: https://caniuse.com/?search=content

There you can search for features and check, if theyre available in certain browsers. In your case, content is basically (officialy) not supported.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't do this by animating content as it isn't implemented in all browsers, you can use a CSS variable as the content and change that in JS every 9 seconds - defining the variable in the span element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background: black;/*added so can see the text */
}
    .wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 20%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .wrapper h2 {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
    span:before {
        content: var(--content);
        font-family: 'Spectral', serif;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
            body{
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .wrapper {
                top: 50vh;
                left: 50vw;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Investments for <span></span></h2>
    </div>
    <script>
    const span = document.querySelector('.wrapper h2 span');
    const messages = ['a better future', 'a better life', 'prosperity'];
    const messagesLength = messages.length;
    let messageNumber = 0;

    function setMessage() {
      span.style.setProperty('--content', "'" + messages[messageNumber] + "'");
      messageNumber = (messageNumber + 1)%messagesLength;
      }
      
    setInterval(setMessage, 9000);
    setMessage();
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```